# How to add hyperlink to PDF using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I’m generating figures with Matplotlib’s PDF backend:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Foo')
plt.savefig('bar.pdf', format='pdf')
```

What are my options to render the title (or any other label) a clickable hyperlink?

Comment: Maybe rendering text labels through latex would provide a way to do this

Comment: @MichaelGoerz: like the idea, but that wouldn't be a viable option when generating a large  amount of figures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the PGF backend, you gain the full flexibility of LaTeX, including the possibility to define hyperlinks (or internal references):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('pgf')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
matplotlib.rcParams['pgf.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{hyperref}', ]

plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{time} (s)')
plt.ylabel(r'\textit{voltage} (mV)')
plt.title(r"\href{http://www.google.com}{This title links to google}", color='gray')

plt.savefig('tex_demo.pdf')
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get this to work with other backends (setting `text.latex.preamble` instead of `pgf.preamble`). It appears that while other backends also process the strings through latex, they strip out the hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though it’s not using the PDF backend, it provides a good alternative! I’ll be waiting for a solution using the PDF backend before accepting your answer.